# RAM issues with one hot encoding

Tags: keras, google-colaboratory, recurrent-neural-network, one-hot-encoding

I know there's been several posts on this, but recently I ran into some RAM issues for a large text while doing one hot encoding for a Bidirectional LSTM.

Checking online, I discovered there were alternative ways to address this with sklearn or introducing an embedding to layer to keras, which is what I tried here:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add((OneHot(input_dim=vocab_size, input_length= seq_length)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(rnn_size, activation="relu"),input_shape=(seq_length, vocab_size)))
```

Everything seemed fine here, but then I needed to fit my model (model.fit) along with the typical inputs and outputs parameters. I tried to randomize these variables, and that was when the RAM really blew up.

```
X = np.random.random((len(sequences), seq_length, vocab_size))
y = np.random.randint(2, size=(len(sequences), vocab_size))
```

Any suggestions on how I could prevent it (either in the final step or along the way)?

Answer (score 0):

dont use `model.fit` but instead use `model.train_on_batch` that way you dont have to load entire dataset. you only need a single batch of 32 or 64 whatever you choose.

model.train_on_batch need a loop for each item in batch, and another loop for epoch.

**my code for video action recognition** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EliLhaAf-So

this code is on colab, and it implement same technique that i am talking about here.